# How to define Turkish character to QStringList on QT

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, qstring, qlocale

I want to define QString Turkish Character on Qt. I define below:

```
QString aa="çİĞ";
```

I want to see aa

```
qDebug()<<aa;
```

it is difference, how to set turkish character QString

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works for me as expected. I assume your terminal does not use UTF-8 to display text.

Comment: what do i need to do

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: Non-ascii characters might be problematic at several places: source file encoding, compiler charset, console settings.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: ı use windows operating system